# Array of Class Error

Tags: c#

So i have this class

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{ 
    public class Records
    {
        public string name, surname;

        public int num;
    }
}
```

And i want to create an array of this class, tried everything and it still doesn't work, i started to think it is a bug, i am using Visual Studio 2012, here is my code.Any help would be appreciated.

(there is a datagrid of records on a form, which i'm reading from a textbox, informations are seperated with tab character)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Records[] userRecs = new Records[20];

        public int count = 0;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getText();
        }

        public void getText() 
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\filestr.txt",FileMode.Open);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

            for (string readed = sr.ReadLine(); readed != null; readed = sr.ReadLine())
            {
                string[] tempStr = readed.Split('\t');

                userRecs[count].num = Convert.ToInt32(tempStr[0]);

                userRecs[count].name = tempStr[1];

                userRecs[count].surname = tempStr[2];

                count++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(userRecs[count].num, userRecs[count].name, userRecs[count].surname);
            }

            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: what error do you get, where?

Comment: Even if you get it to work use list!

Comment: You need to allocate memory as well to the array.

Comment: You will have a problem if there are more than 20 lines in the file since your array can only hold 20 items!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This allocates memory for the array, but does not create Record instances:

```
Records[] userRecs = new Records[20];
```

Now when you're iterating through your file lines, you need to instantiate your class:

```
userRecs[count] = new Records();
userRecs[count].num = ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(userRecs[count].num, userRecs[count].name, userRecs[count].surname);
```

probably should be

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(userRecs[i].num, userRecs[i].name, userRecs[i].surname);
```

Comment: It shouldn't account for the error. But that's a possible bug you found :)

Comment: The NullReferenceException, most likely.  No "Records" is ever allocated.

Comment: Yea, i noticed i just recreated code to paste here normally that wasnt the case, ty anyway :)